# Почему не логинит Google с помощью Laravel Socialite?

Tags: laravel, google-oauth2

Laravel 6

Успешно настроил авторизацию через Фейсбук и ВК

Гугл внедрить тем же самым способом не получается.

Код:

Редирект на провайдера

```
return Socialite::driver($name)->redirect();
```

Прием ответа соцсети

```
Socialite::driver($name)->user();
```

Получаю 500 ошибку. В логах:

```
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project номер before or i (truncated...)
{"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException(code: 403): Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` resulted in a `403 Forbidden`
```

Ошибка одинаковая и на локалхосте и на продакшене.

В https://console.developers.google.com
Указал название и линки в разделе Окно запроса доступа OAuth.

Также создал учетные данные в разделе Идентификаторы клиентов OAuth 2.0, откуда взял ид приложения и секрет.
Данные перепроверил 10 раз все правильное. В любом случае ругается не на неправильные данные.

Также на саму почту гугла после попытки авторизации пришло оповещение:

> Теперь у приложения есть доступ к Вашему аккаунту Google.

Т.е. у приложения доступ есть, а у сайта нет. Как заставить гугл работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Провайдер Laravel Socialite для Google полностью нерабочий. Все ссылки запросов, обработка ответов, хелперы - все устарело. Странно что нигде нет об этом информации, учитывая популярность фреймворка и гугла

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
Socialite::driver($name)->user();
```

используйте:

```
Socialite::with($name)->user();
```

Вместо: "google" -> "Google"